# Disable element based on class

Tags: jquery

I want to disable some tr's based on some condition, i.e. if class is present or not for that particular tr.

```
if (self.EmailDetailsList.length <= 4) {
                    self.EmailDetailsList.push(data);
                    event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.className = 'highlightRow';
                    self.isSelected(true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#addresslistId tr").prop('disabled', true);
                }
```

Here if a tr which does not have class 'highlightRow' should be disabled, using jquery.
Please suggest a nice approach

Comment: `disable` tr's? I think you need to disable its children i.e. input

Comment: how will you disable a tr?

Comment: only form elements gets enable/disable not the table div etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here if a tr which does not have class 'highlightRow' should be
>   disabled, using jquery. Please suggest a nice approach

You can't disable a `<tr>`, but you can disable all inputs. We use `$.not` to remove `<tr>` which have the class and disable those which doesn't have it.

```
$('tr').not('.highlightRow').find(":input").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Amit, Its working, ya sorry tr cant be disabled, i thought whole element and its child will be disabled.